# Is there a way to capture failed EMails using MailApp?

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I use MailApp in a Google Script program in this manner:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(AddressStringGlobal,EMailSubjectProperLanguageGlobal,"",{htmlBody: EMailBody});
```

My problem is that, if I have a bad EMail address in my data, my program blows up.  Let's say the bad EMail is in the 50th row of 100 rows of data.  Then 49 EMails go out and 51 don't.

the error that I receive is:

```
Invalid email: org (line 707, file, "code")
```

I can't see it in the description of the class MailApp, but I was wondering if there was a way to capture the fact that an EMail has failed so that can handle that in my code, rather than have the program blow up.  I'd be open to different EMail facility if it had such a feature or any other advice.

Comment: Thanks TJ.  Can you point me to where I can learn about try/catch?

Comment: That worked like a champ TJ.  On the 1st try!  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `MailApp.sendEmail` throws an error in certain error conditions. If so, you can use `try`/`catch` to catch the error and continue processing:

```
for (/*...your loop...*/) {
    try {
        MailApp.sendEmail(AddressStringGlobal,EMailSubjectProperLanguageGlobal,"",{htmlBody: EMailBody});
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle/report the error
    }
}
```

That way, the error doesn't terminate your loop.

More on `try`/`catch` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).